# animate controls as part of the image

Tags: animate

This is a "nice to have"-question, I guess:

I'm using the `animate` package to show a sequence of software dialog screenshots. In getting through the series I added that useful but ugly looking controls panel (yes, I have tried different fg/bg-colors ... it didn't make the thing better). The screenshots are these usual `<BACK/NEXT>` dialogs.

Is it possible to get the animation command FORWARD/BACKWARD in these `NEXT>` and `<BACK` button areas in the screenshots, so that -- similar to the real software -- the reader must click to 'NEXT' in the sceenshot to get the next pic and clicking 'BACK' shows the previous screenshot?

Hope, I could express it understandable ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice example of using the JavaScript API of `animate` and the `\mediabutton` command of `media9`.

User Caramdir's excellent [onimage](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/download/head:/onpicture.dtx-20110408004903-647028sl4xn4pwd3-1/onimage.dtx) package is used to place the buttons onto the animation. However, we have to patch `onimage.sty` in order to not use `\includegraphics`.

For the code below to compile, copy the example image files from package `mwe` into the current directory as

```
cp $TEXMF/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.png ./example-image-1.png
cp $TEXMF/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b.png ./example-image-2.png
cp $TEXMF/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-c.png ./example-image-3.png
```

since we need numbered images for `\animategraphics`.

### [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9} % buttons via \mediabutton

%get it from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/onimage.dtx
\usepackage{onimage}

%patch onimage.sty not to use \includegraphics
\makeatletter
\def\tikzonimage@opt[#1]#2{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\node[inner sep=0] (image) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
        \node[inner sep=0] (image) {#2};
        \begin{tikzonnode}{image}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  \begin{tikzonimage}{%
    \animategraphics[method=ocg,label=myGUI,step,nomouse,width=0.8\linewidth]{1}{example-image-}{1}{3}
  }[tsx/show help lines]
    \node at (0.8 , 0.8) [anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {
      \mediabutton[
        jsaction={try{anim.myGUI.frameNum--}catch(e){}}
      ]{\fbox{\small\strut back}}};
    \node at (0.8 , 0.8) [anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {
      \mediabutton[
        jsaction={try{anim.myGUI.frameNum++}catch(e){}}
      ]{\fbox{\small\strut next}}};
  \end{tikzonimage}  

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uh ... wow, how cool is that? Exactlely what I was looking for => THANKS!!!